# Enable/Disable Log4jLogger programmatically?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am using org.slf4j.Logger and org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.

Following instance for Logger is getting picked at runtime :

org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger

I want to enable/disable all logging at runtime.
Other answers mentioned setting log level OFF after casting Logger into ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger but this won't work for me.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think logback which you mentioned can totally work, maybe your configuration is wrong somewhere.

You need to add the scan option in logback.xml. Something like this

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">
<appender name="A1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${jstorm.log.dir}/${topology.name:-.}/${logfile.name}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.roll
```